# Show State/Province code in address

Tags: shipping-address, ce-1.9.2.4, code, country-regions, regions

When a customer make an order, in the shipping and billing address appears the extended Province name (for example "Lecce"). Is it possible to show the Region code "LE" instead of the Region name "Lecce"?

Here there is the DB structure:

```
Country ID > IT
Code (Region code) > LE
Default_name (Region name) > Lecce
```

I don't want to modify directly this table "directory_country_region" in the DB.

Comment: Where do you want to show this ? In admin side or in customer account section ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at-least in two ways.

### 1. Observer way - Recommending Way

If you want to see this change in admin side, then you can observe to the event `customer_address_format` and define following observer method within it.

```
public function changeRegionText(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $address = $observer->getAddress();
    //makes sure change apply to only billing and shipping address types
    if ($address->getAddressType()=='shipping' || $address->getAddressType()=='billing') {
        $code = $address->getRegionCode();
        $address->setRegion($code);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, I am just grabbing region code from address entity and then forcefully set it as region.

You can also listen to a '*broader event*' `sales_order_address_collection_load_after` and do the same thing by looping through the collection. ie.

```
public function changeRegionText(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderAddressCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $address) {
        
        //makes sure change apply to only billing and shipping address types
        if ($address->getAddressType()=='shipping' || $address->getAddressType()=='billing') {
            $code = $address->getRegionCode();
            $address->setRegion($code);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This broader way allows to give your change permanently everywhere in your instance.

### 2. Rewrite Way - Easy Nasty Way

If you want to do the change in admin side, then you need to rewrite block class `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default` through your module and customize `render()` method.

This is because this class what actually responsible for rendering billing & shipping address in admin side. You need to replace below code line

```
$data['region'] = Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegion());
```

with

```
$data['region'] = Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegionCode());
```

which you can find inside `render()` method.

Comment: which files have I to modify?

Comment: you need to create a module in this case to do both case 1 and 2. I

Comment: What should be the file config.xml?

Comment: @stsnow In order to create a module, multiple files are involving in it. You should know how to create a stand alone module in Magento in order to understand and implement idea which I shared above.